# Eloquent Laravel sort paginate query by related model

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have the following Eloquent query.

```php
Company::has('cars')->with([
    'cars', 'location' => function ($q) {
        $q->nearBy(); // *** See futher
    }
])->take(40)->paginate(10);
```

How can I order the Companies by distance?

*** This is the NearBy Scope in the `Location`-model:

```php
public function scopeNearBy($query)
{
    $location = json_decode(request()->cookie('location'));
    $query->distance($location->lat, $location->lng); // ** Using package

    return $query->orderBy('distance');
}
```

** Which uses [this package](https://github.com/malhal/Laravel-Geographical).

The calculation of the distances is OK and works when I call the following.

```php
\App\Address::nearBy()->get()
```

Comment: did you got any errors?

Comment: Please post the `cars` relationship.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir you can skip the cars relationship, query is the same idea but then not with cars added to the response - it's a hasmany relationship.

Comment: @ChamaraAbeysekara no, query works, but it's not order by distance of the location at all.

Comment: @user1469734 If its work with `\App\Address::nearBy()->get()` , then it seems like you are wrongfully mapping distance in scopeNearBy function. 
if it is, then can you please provide us relevant model file also? that will help me to find the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to join location table to Company query, and then you can order by distance.

Comment: This. For years i hoped to solve this problem with a simple orderBy from Eloquent, but each time i end up doing a join and ordering like this. Today i honestly think that's the only way to natively do it.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the only way is to store the distance of each location when they are added. Then, of course, you can order them by distance.

Answer (score 0):

if you can find distance using that package . Append the distance to your Company Model.

Then you can easily sort the collection in controller

refer https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-sortby